# Android Bundle ArrayOutOfBoundException when getting data

Tags: android, android-bundle

I'm using a bundle to pass data between thread.
 Sometime when i try to read the data's bundle i got an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=4
        at android.util.ArrayMap.indexOf(ArrayMap.java:110)
        at android.util.ArrayMap.indexOfKey(ArrayMap.java:339)
        at android.util.ArrayMap.get(ArrayMap.java:381)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getByte(BaseBundle.java:693)
        at android.os.Bundle.getByte(Bundle.java:579)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getByte(BaseBundle.java:680)
        at android.os.Bundle.getByte(Bundle.java:566)
        at com.online.libcommunication.net.ThreadD.handleMessage(ThreadD.java:425)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

The code triggering the exception is :

```
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(!this.isAlive()) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case ThreadMessages.MSG_CMD : 
                bundle = msg.getData();
                byte modecmd = bundle.getByte("mode", (byte) 127); // <-- This is the line causing the exception
                // ...
                return true;
        }
    }
```

And that's how the bundle is created on the other thread :

```
public void sendCommand(Bundle bundle,DPO dpo)
    {
        Message msg = mPHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.what = ThreadMessages.MSG_CMD;
        msg.obj = dpo;
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mPHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    bc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                mCmdBundle.clear();
                mCmdBundle.putByte("mode", (byte) 6);
                // + Other datas
                mActivity.getController().sendCommand(mCmdBundle, mDPO);
        }
    });
```

I don't really understand what is happening , it's almost like the getX method from the bundle is not finding the associated key and throw an exception instead of a default value.
The exception also happen randomly, sometime it's working fine.

I could simply wrap the all thing in a try/catch but i'd rather understand the root of the problem.

Any ideas ?

Edit : Running on Android 5.1.1

Comment: What is the Android version of the device on which these crashes are occurring?

Comment: It's running on 5.1.1 so the bug should be fixed. I'll try on a newer version of android.

Comment: Can you also try `mCmdBundle = new Bundle()` instead of `mCmdBundle.clear()`?

Answer (score 1):

After researching on your issue as it doesn't feel usual.

I found this: [Google bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37005805) It's on `android.util.ContainerHelpers.binarySearch`

Google says they have fixed this issue in Android 5.1.

But there are similar occurrences on newer versions too.

It might be related. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if bundle contains key "mode" before taking the value. Seems it's a bug in Bundle ArrayMap